# How to split the comma separated values from a row and convert into columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a `LIST_OF_PRODUCTS` table containing:

```
Product ID  Product Name  Product Region
1           LG TV         North;South;North East
2           Sony Bravia   East;West
3           Samsung TV    East;North East;South West
```

I would like to split the delimited Product Region values from the table and make them individual columns, and show the availability of the product based on its region, so I end up with:

```
Product ID  Product Name  North  South  East  West  NorthEast  SouthWest
1           LG TV             1      1     0     0          1          0
2           Sony Bravia       0      0     1     1          0          0
3           Samsung TV        0      0     1     0          1          1
```

How can I split them out like this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at the pivot functionality available in 11g?

Comment: It is working for the following case (NORTH,SOUTH,EAST,WEST).  But in other cases (North East, South West) is not working.

Comment: What is working and not working? You haven't shown any code...

Answer (score 1):

Using a series of case when statements could give you near to what you want.

That would look something like this:

```
select product_id, product_name, 
case when instr(product_region,'North')>0 then 1 else 0 end as North,
case when instr(product_region,'East')>0 then 1 else 0 end as East,
case when instr(product_region,'South')>0 then 1 else 0 end as South,
case when instr(product_region,'West')>0 then 1 else 0 end as West,
from list_of_products;
```

Where that gets tricky is that that your regional enumeration {North,East,South,West,North East,North West,South East,South West } doesn't properly respond to a simple instr search - because 'North' matches 'North', 'North East' and 'North West' - so you'd have to either change your regional enumeration to a scheme that doesn't work like that. e.g. {North_,East_,South_,West_,NorthEast_,NorthWest_,SouthEast_,SouthWest_} It only has to be temporary, so maybe you could pass the region field through some kind of subquery.

Comment: thanks.  But when handling a bulk of data, How can I code the datas in case statement?? To handling a lot of data, Do you suggest any alteranate way??

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a 'bulk of data' - do you have volume vertically (i.e. lots of rows) or horizontally (lots of possible columns)?